# Polymorphic Association other than model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, polymorphic-associations

I have two models:

*Payment.rb*

```
belongs_to :payer, polymorphic: true, required: true
belongs_to :payable, polymorphic: true
belongs_to :sponsor, -> { where(payments: { payable_type: 'Sponsor' }) },
                          foreign_key: 'payable_id'`
```

*Sponsor.rb*

```
has_many :payments, as: :payable, dependent: :destroy
```

I am able to create payment using `payable_type` "sponsor" and `payable_id`  "sponsor_id".
I can access `@payment.payable`

**Result for this is payable_type is sponsor.**

I want to store payable type as `sponsorship` and model for it obviously Sponsor. If I will access `@payment.payable`.

**Result for this should be payable_type is Sponsorship.**

Any suggestions welcome as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

No other way I could think of for this.

```
class Sponsor < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Sponsorship < Sponsor
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. but it did not for me.